# Do I need an amplifier to listen to the signal audio coming from a DAC?

Tags: audio, conversion, signal-processing

I'm planning to use a DAC (digital-analog converter) to convert signal from an optical/toslink connection (Apple TV) to my speakers with 3.5 analog jack.

I'm wondering if I need an amplifier or if I can just connect the speakers (or eventually headphones) to the converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3.5mm analog jack should be an output at line level. This means that most headphones (not high-end audiophile headphones) should work well.

If you mean computer speakers, yes, they will work from that output as they are equipped with an internal amplifier. Larger speakers for home listening use will require a separate amplifier, as is the case with CD players, FM tuners, etc.

Just a note, this question may be considered off-topic for this forum as it is more concerned with home audio than audio production. I am not sure if stack exchange has a home entertainment forum. If not, it may be possible to suggest one.

Comment: P.S. It should not be possible to simply connect speakers that require an amplifier to a 3.5mm jack.

Comment: Thanks, just to be sure: these are my speakers: http://www.englishforum.ch/attachments/sale-wanted/8101d1249885281-oerlikon-sale-computer-speakers-harman-kardon-soundsticks-4116yt828dl.jpg

Comment: I think they have indeed their own internal amplifier. Correct?

Comment: Yes, you can connect those right to the DAC without anything in between.

Comment: Ok perfect. One last question, I've just checked this converter on amazon. Does it have the correct input/outputs ports ? (Is the toslink input correct ?) http://www.amazon.de/Digital-Toslink-Analog-stereo-Konverter/dp/B004O2P0CS/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1343804303&sr=8-1

Comment: This is the AppleTV output: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7c/Apple_TV_2nd_Generation_back.jpg/220px-Apple_TV_2nd_Generation_back.jpg

Comment: Or this one also: http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B002AKXG5E/sr=8-2/qid=1343805256/ref=olp_product_details?ie=UTF8&me=&qid=1343805256&seller=&sr=8-2

Comment: Both of those should work well. Toslink is what you would use, because that is the output the AppleTV provides.